# Need help in serialization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

Been spending my last two hours trying to learn how to serialize my data i need a code that serializes my data in "StatContainer" i tried this :

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934

and alot more but i wasnt able to understand how to serialize my data

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Stats : MonoBehaviour 
{
    StatContainer stats = new StatContainer();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("AddCoins", 4.0f, 2.0f);
        InvokeRepeating ("AddScore", 1.5f, 1.5f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        this.stats.Update();
    }

    void AddCoins (){       
        if (BunnyScript.BunnyAlive == true) {
            StatContainer.coins += 1;    
        }
    }

    void AddScore (){
        if (BunnyScript.BunnyAlive == true) {
            StatContainer.score += 1;
        }
    }
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class StatContainer
    {
    public static int coins = 0;
    public static int totalcoins = 0;
    public static int score = 0;

    public static int personalbest = 0;
    public static float UmbrellaSpeed = 0.1f;
    public static float currentumbdur = 500;

    public static int CarrotSpawnRateLVL = 1;
    public static float CarrotSpawnRate = 60f;
    public static int CarrotSpawnRateUpgradeCost = 15;


    public static int UmbrellaDurabilityLVL = 1;
    public static float UmbrellaDurability = 500;
    public static int UmbrellaDurabilityUpgradeCost = 30;

    public static int UmbrellaSizeLVL = 1;
    public static float UmbrellaSize = 0f;
    public static int UmbrellaSizeUpgradeCost = 25;


    public static int CarrotEffectLVL = 1;
    public static float CarrotEffect = 20;
    public static int CarrotEffectUpgradeCost = 25;


    public static int HealthRegenLVL = 1;
    public static float HealthRegenTime = 4f;
    public static int HealthRegenCost = 100;


    public static int BuyTreesCost = 250;

    public static int Tree1Bought = 0;
    public static float Tree1Size = 0;
    public static int Tree1SizeLVL = 1;
    public static int Tree1SizeUpgradeCost = 50;

    public static int Tree2Bought = 0;
    public static float Tree2Size = 0;
    public static int Tree2SizeLVL = 1;
    public static int Tree2SizeUpgradeCost = 50;

    public static int Tree3Bought = 0;
    public static float Tree3Size =0;
    public static int Tree3SizeLVL = 1;
    public static int Tree3SizeUpgradeCost = 50;
    // and the rest

    public void Update(){
        if (score > personalbest) {
            personalbest = score;
        }
    }
}
```

this is how i try to serialize it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; 
using System.IO;

public static class SaveLoad {
    public static List<StatContainer> savedGames = new List<StatContainer>();

    //it's static so we can call it from anywhere
    public static void Save() {
        SaveLoad.savedGames.Add(StatContainer.current);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        //Application.persistentDataPath is a string, so if you wanted you can put that into debug.log if you want to know where save games are located
        FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd"); //you can call it anything you want
        bf.Serialize(file, SaveLoad.savedGames);
        file.Close();
    }   

    public static void Load() {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd")) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd", FileMode.Open);
            SaveLoad.savedGames = (List<StatContainer>)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

i am calling the load fuction in the beggining of the game and the save using invoke repeating every 2 sec

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: how do i serialize the data in StatContainer

Comment: You need to add more information about your problem.

Comment: Okay i added more info

Comment: I'm not an expert, but, I if I were you, I would not declare the class' attributes `static`.

Comment: @Hellium if they are not static they cant be accesed from other scripts

Comment: You got it wrong, if they are not static, they belong to the object instead of the class. You can still access a variable if public. But usually you keep all variables private and make public methods to modify them. See how you are calling stats.Update, this is how you would call non-static members.

Answer (score 0):

First remove static members in *StatContainer*
To access your data make Load function return *StatContainer* and in your class *Stats* you can put *StatContainer* in static or create a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) of *Stats*.

Second I don't know your purpose but perhaps you can take a look to [xml serialization](http://tlevesque.developpez.com/dotnet/xml-serialization/) instead of *BinaryFormat*, to have a file who is readable by human and so you can change easely the data.
 In that case I sugest to you, to take a look to *Xml tags* like below.
(And you can encrypt your xml when you release your game)

```
[System.Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "stats-of-something")]
public class StatContainer
{
     [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "coins")]
     public int coins = 0;
     [XmlElement(ElementName = "umbrella-speed")]
     public float UmbrellaSpeed = 0.1f;
}
```

or

```
[System.Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "stats-of-something")]
public class StatContainer
{
     [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "coins")]
     private int _coins = 0;
     [XmlElement(ElementName = "umbrella-speed")]
     private float _umbrellaSpeed = 0.1f;

     public int coins { get { return _coins; } set { _coins = value; } }
     public float umbrellaSpeed  { get { return _umbrellaSpeed ; } set { _umbrellaSpeed = value; } }
}
```